# What is the closest candidate for Dark Matter currently?

Tags: solar-system, dark-matter, dark-energy

I've both fascinated and frustrated after learning about the existence of Dark Matter.

Can we find evidence of Dark Matter within our Solar system? What is currently the closest candidate for Dark Matter?

And please let me know what are good online resources where I can stay up to date with information about this?

Comment: You are asking about two very different things "Dark Matter" and "Dark Energy".  Apart from the word "Dark" they are not really related. Please split into separate questions, and be sure to explain what prior research you have done on each question.

Comment: @JamesK Oh I asked based on the fact that dark matter and dark energy are manifestations of the same dark "thing". Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close, as sub-questions 1 & 2 are substantially different and therefore the overall question is too broad. There are multiple candidates for dark matter so I also think #2 invites opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5534) arxiv post says if there is dark matter in the solar systems, its density should be below $\approx 1.4\cdot 10^{-20} \frac{g}{cm^3}$.

They tried to find the dark matter in the solar systems by measuring its possible gravitational effects.

Note, it is a negative result, i.e. they didn't find anything, but they are suspecting, if the dark matter density would be at least $\approx 1.4\cdot 10^{-20} \frac{g}{cm^3}$, they had found it.

There are [various candidates](https://www.sciencealert.com/from-machos-to-wimps-meet-the-top-five-candidates-for-dark-matter) what could it be, the currently considered most probable are the [WIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles)s (particles interacting only gravitationally and maybe weakly).

Comment: Interesting. FWIW, if the Earth is permeated by dark matter at that density, it contains around 15 metric tons of DM.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, as far I know there were tries to build big detectors similar to the neutrino detectors, to detect it by its weak interaction.